# Dialog not Opening

Tags: java, android

This my code which is supposed to open a list view of items. And when an item is clicked it opens a corresponding dialog. The listView appears but no dialog shows at all. And I don't see any errors in the logcat. Please help

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.playmaker.BudgetOh.R;
import com.playmaker.BudgetOh.manager.ExpenseManager;
import com.playmaker.BudgetOh.model.Expense;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewExpense extends ListActivity {
ExpenseManager expenseManager;
ArrayList<Expense> allExpenses;
ArrayList<String> allTitles;
ListView listView;
String titlePosition;
Dialog dialog;
Expense expense;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    expenseManager = new ExpenseManager(this);
    allTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    allExpenses = expenseManager.getAllExpenses();
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.viewBackground);
    listView.setPadding(10, 20, 10, 15);
    listView.setFooterDividersEnabled(true);
    listView.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);

    // getting all the titles
    for (Expense expense : allExpenses) {

        allTitles.add(expense.getTitle());
    }
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allTitles));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    titlePosition = allTitles.get(position);
    expense = expenseManager.getExpense(titlePosition);

    dialog = new Dialog(ViewExpense.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_details);

    TextView tvTime, tvTitle, tvAmount, tvCategory, tvComment;

    tvTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewTitle);
    tvAmount = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewAmount);
    tvCategory = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewCategory);
    tvComment = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewComment);
    tvTime = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewTime);

    dialog.setTitle(expense.getTitle());
    tvTitle.setText(expense.getTitle());
    tvAmount.setText(expense.getAmount());
    tvCategory.setText(expense.getCategory());
    tvComment.setText(expense.getComment());
    tvTime.setText("Created on " + expense.getDate() + " At  "
            + expense.getTime());
    dialog.show();

}

}
```

This is my dialog layout

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Cream_Back"android:layout_width="match_parent"android:layout_height="match_parent"android:alpha="0.5"android:orientation="vertical"><LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E3CF57"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Expense Title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tvViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="fill|center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E3CF57"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Expense Amount"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tvViewAmount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="fill|center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E3CF57"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Expense Category"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tvViewCategory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="fill|center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E3CF57"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Time Recorded"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tvViewTime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="fill|center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#E3CF57"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tvViewComment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="fill|center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please what exception?

Comment: If there is any exception paste log cat also and u forgot to end </ScrollView> in your dialog layout.

Comment: are you sure your onListItemClick works? It´s possible that the whole event doesn´t work, not only the dialog..

Comment: what problem are you facing ? what is the logcat display ? please do post logcat here .

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment but what I see in your xml is that you do not close properly. You need to close with `</Scrollview>` instead of `</LinearLayout>`. Also make sure the ScrollView hosts just one View, so just wrap your LinearLayout-Views with a RelativeLayout.

Try it and see if dialog opens.

Answer (score 0):

Android's **ScrollView** states that ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)):

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in
>   it containing the entire contents to scroll;

- According to your .xml, there are several LinearLayouts (multiple childs) inside the ScrollView thus is not accepted by FrameLayout's rules; I see all LinearLayouts are vertical oriented, so you can agglomerate all-in-one possibly;
- Also, ScrollView is not closed properly (`</ScrollView>` missing).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are getting values for "allTitles".

Modify your code for the values, Below is the code. It's working fine.

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
//ExpenseManager expenseManager;
ArrayList<Expense> allExpenses;
ArrayList<String> allTitles;
ListView listView;
String titlePosition;
Dialog dialog;
Expense expense;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //expenseManager = new ExpenseManager(this);
    allTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    //allExpenses = expenseManager.getAllExpenses();
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
    listView.setPadding(10, 20, 10, 15);
    listView.setFooterDividersEnabled(true);
    listView.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);

    // getting all the titles

    allTitles.add("ANup");
    allTitles.add("Tamal");
    allTitles.add("Aditya");

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allTitles));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    titlePosition = allTitles.get(position);
    //expense = expenseManager.getExpense(titlePosition);

    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    TextView tvTime, tvTitle, tvAmount, tvCategory, tvComment;

    tvTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewTitle);
    tvAmount = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewAmount);
    tvCategory = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewCategory);
    tvComment = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewComment);
    tvTime = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvViewTime);

    dialog.setTitle("Hello");
    tvTitle.setText("Expenase Test");
    tvAmount.setText("$ 100");
    tvCategory.setText("Travel");
    tvComment.setText("Enjoyed!");
    tvTime.setText("Created on " + "Apr 18th" + " At  "
            + "4:20 PM");
    dialog.show();
}
```

}